# Tortoise subversion server v1.14 very slow Windows11 with svn://localhost syntax

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ipv6, ipv4, visualsvn

I just built a fast new Windows11 machine, installed the latest TortoiseSVN (1.14), created new repositories, started a Windows service (all on the local C: drive), and am experiencing what feels like slow delays in doing simple checking on small VS C# projects.

For example, I click okay on the VisualSVN (VS2019 extension) OK button to do a check-in, and then I have to wait for 10 seconds or maybe longer for the check-in to complete. Ten seconds won't kill me, but on my Windows10 machine, checkins to the local repositories there take 2 seconds or something like that. On my new Win11 machine, check-ins using the file:///C:/xxx syntax are essentially instant - no observable delays at all.

The Win11 check-in dialog said "207 bytes transferred in 7 seconds" for a small VStudio project of 5 files and a few hundred lines of code using the svn://localhost/xxx syntax. I have the 'recurse into unversioned folders' flag off as described on another SO post, but that did not make any difference.

It's almost like there is a network timeout going on between the client and server before the check-in proceeds, but I can't think of a reason why that would be the case. I'm on a new machine with defaults for the clients and servers and ports, so I can't think of a reason for timeouts to occur.

Are there other flags that I should disable? Does anyone think an IPv6 and IPv4 fallback is occurring? I haven't seen any svn operations to set IPv6 vs IPv4 options in the configuration.

I'm thinking I should just switch to the file:///C:/xxx syntax to try to speed things up on my local machine, but I read elsewhere on SO that using the file:///C:/xxx syntax is not a good practice (esp if the repo is accessed by other machines over the net with svn://xxx syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check the configuration of your SVN server. Since you say that the problem occurs when you use the svn:// protocol, it means that you expose your repositories via the svnserve-based server and I'm pretty sure that you configured the server from ground up.
- See if the problem occurs when you access your repositories via HTTP(S). E.g., [install VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) and see if the delay occurs when you contact your repositories.
- Check your antivirus. It is possible that an antivirus application is causing these delays.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I didn't configure the server at all beyond the usual command line 'svnserve --service -r path'. I did more digging. Response is instant with svn://127.0.0.1/, not-so-instant with svn://localhost/ (internal DNS lookup required), and slow with svn://myhostname-in-the-hosts-file/, and dead slow with svn://myhostname-not-in-the-hosts-file. The instant response with 127.0.0.1 means the issue is a lookup issue and that my server/repositories are fine (as they should be, they are all new).

Comment: I wish I knew why adding my hostname to the hosts file does not give me the same speed as 127.0.0.1. I suppose as a workaround I can check everything out again using svn://127.0.01/ so VisualSVN will use that as the default address. I'm just on a home network, but as you know DNS lookups for machines inside home networks don't work by default (AFAIK) without some router work. Maybe if svn had a way of talking to a local DNS things would be faster, but even lookups to the hosts file are apparently slow.